# SSIS SQL Task not returning string date

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to run the below procedure from SSIS using SQL Task.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Previous_Load_Dt_Tm]
AS
BEGIN

SELECT Extract_Dt_Tm =  ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), MAX([Previous_Load_Date_Time]),120),'')
FROM [Test_table] WITH (NOLOCK)

END
```

I am returning as below

[image]

When I use the variable type as String in SSIS :

[image]

If I update the variable type to date it gives me the value:

[image]

Question ) I am not sure why its returning a date when I am converting the date to varchar in the procedure.

Comment: I am using SSIS version 14

Comment: Are you sure that the value is not stored in the variable? Have you tried to debug and watch your local variables?

Comment: Yes I had been sending them to a log table!!!

Answer (score 1):

Is this happening at run time?

If you change the variable type to `datetime` at design time, and the string returned from the stored procedure is written to it during execution, this would most likely be due to SSIS performing an implicit conversion, i.e. successfully parsing a `datetime` value from the string.

I imagine the images you posted are at design time, with the string not having been written yet, and the `datetime` having defaulted to the current date and time?

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris!!! I had been going crazy with this so I just removed and re added the variable and started to work.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed and re added the variable. And it worked!!!! Not sure what the issue was.